# Error: Infinity loop recursion javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am beginner javascript. I tried to debug my function browseDom. When it runs to node head[2]=text, mean i=2. I think it will continue with i=3 at head parent but I don't understand why i=0???

[image]

```
 function browseDom(parent){
            i=0;
            while(parent.childNodes[i]){
                browseDom(parent.childNodes[i]);
                i=i+1;
            }
    }
```

Comment: why not use a for loop?

Comment: Why not use a `for...each` loop?

Comment: Your `i` is the same for each function, change `i=0;` to `var i=0;`

Comment: Because i don't know height of the tree dom, this picture just is a simple example

Comment: Yes var i work well, but why

Comment: @KevinKloet @coldspeed How can a `for loop` handle multiple level of data? I swear the god if you say to use nested `for` loop I kill myself ^_^

Comment: See the dupe target: Same problem, same explanation of the fix.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT `for loop` is to iterate through children, not to replace the recursive function.

Comment: @NathanP. Oh ok then :)

Comment: Thanks everybody